# Passing a file into ModelBuilder based on user input string

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

What I need to do is pass a string into my model to tell it to look in a certain file for a State's road network kind of like this:

```
C:\Users\User1\Documents\ArcGIS\USA\%State%\Shape\GU_IncorporatedPlace.shp
```

Where "%State%" is a user input string. I've tried the Parse Path tool but I'm not sure how to load the file into the Model.

Comment: Not sure if it's quite what you are looking for but have you tried the [Select Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//004000000009000000) model tool.

Comment: On your suggestion I tried this but it doesn't seem to load the shapefile? No errors are thrown but no file is loaded. http://i.imgur.com/2PvTdxm.png that is a screen grab of the model

Comment: are you planning to iterate through different state folders?

Comment: I will manually input each state as a parameter of the model. My goal is to build a model that will display that State's road network based on what State I type in. All of the data follows the same path shown above, except for the %State%. So for example if I type "Alabama" then I want to display the road network file located in:

C:\Users\User1\Documents\ArcGIS\USA\Alabama\Shape\GU_IncorporatedPlace.shp where GU_IncorporatedPlace.shp is the road network file

Comment: I believe @Hornbydd had it covered now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Parse Path tool extracts out portions of the input file name. If you read the [help](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000008000000.htm) for this tool and look at the parse_type parameter in the *syntax* section it explains what the tool would generate. So you are using an inappropriate tool.

You could use the the [Calculate Value](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Value/004000000004000000/) tool to generate a FeatureClass object that would feed into another tool, in the example image below I am simply copying the dataset.

[image: Model]

Inside the calculate value tool just set the full path make sure you put that tiny **r** in front of the string and output is FeatureClass.

[image: Calculate value tool]

Comment: This works, just for future reference what is the purpose of r"****"

Comment: If you do not use it, then on a Windows OS the \ symbol is interpreted as an escape character and your file path becomes meaningless.